# How to know version of current-running SAKAI?

Tags: version, sakai

I need to know the version of the hosted and running SAKAI of my group. How can I know that?

Opening the homepage of SAKAI, aftger logged in, it reads the bottom line as below snapshot saying it is `Sakai 1.0 (Kernel 1.3.3)- Server worker1` - does that mean it is version 1?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sakai version 2.9.3 used the kernel version 1.3.3. You can see the versions used for Sakai 2.9.3 in the master pom file:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sakaiproject/master/2.9.3/master-2.9.3.pom

Comment: Note that your hosting provider may have installed newer tools than those listed in that pom to fix bugs or provide features so it may not be 100% accurate.